# Exporting the report in pdf format is having some issues

Tags: java, jasper-reports, dynamic-jasper

I am having some issue while exporting report to the PDF.

[image]

Following are the issues that I am facing

- 2nd and 3rd columns are not proper (one column is left aligned and
  other is right      aligned).
- The last line of the column is getting repeated randomly in some pages. After slno 238
  it is not printing 239 instead it is printing 23 and 9 in two rows with same data.

Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that try setting the **split type** of the band containing the data to **'Prevent'**, this will sustain the splitting of the rows upon the change of the row

**Split Type** is the property of the band, you could access the property by clicking the band node in the **Report Inspector**.

Then the Split Type could be set to **Prevent** which by default is set to '**Stretch**' which tends to split the row when the data overflows from one page to another.

Hope that this works.